# Epson XP-212 does not print

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I've been trying to get an Epson Expression Home XP-212 printer/scanner working on Ubuntu 12.04. From Epson's website I have downloaded and installed the following drivers:

*epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb*

*iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb*

*iscan-data_1.29.0-2_all.deb*

*iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_i386.deb*.

Scanning works fine but printing is the problem. When I'm trying to print a Ubuntu test page, for instance, the result is nothing but a column of letters 'M' etc on the left side of the paper. When trying to print any other file, the paper just flows through the device without any printings.

Because scanning works well, it seems to me that there is a problem with the printer driver although it should be correct.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing `printer-driver-escpr`.

```
 sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no difference when using that driver instead. In fact, I tried that already before. It's strange that almost immediately after trying to print something, there will be a message which says the printing is ready but the paper is still to come out.